# react-router-config и очередность вставки блоков в DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-router, route, router

Доброго дня, наткнулся на такую **проблему**:
Есть конфиг для react-router-config:

```
function getOrderRoutes(prefix = "") {
    if (prefix.length > 0 && !prefix.startsWith("/")) {
        prefix = "/" + prefix;
    }

    return {
        path: `${prefix}/:orderId`,
        component: OrderDetail,
        routes: [{
            path: `${prefix}/:orderId/files`,
            component: OrderFiles
        }, {
            path: `${prefix}/:orderId/:chatId`,
            component: OrderDetail
        }]
    };
}

const routes = [{
    component: Page,
    routes: [{
        path: `/${Url.Menu.BY_MANAGERS}`,
        component: ByManagersMenu,
        routes: [
            {
                path: `/${Url.Menu.BY_MANAGERS}/:userId`,
                component: OrdersListForManager,
                routes: [
                    getOrderRoutes(`/${Url.Menu.BY_MANAGERS}/:userId`)
                ],
            }
        ],

    }, {
        component: redirect(`/${Url.DefaultMenuItem}`),
        path: "/**"
    }],
}];
```

Как я понял, если пользователь дойдёт до максимальной вложенности (допустим /managers/1/1/files) - то реакт роутер отрисует каждый компонент из этой цеочки вложенности по очереди: 
`(Page->ByManagersMenu->OrdersListForManager->OrderDetail->OrderFiles)`

Меня такой вариант устраивает, верстка позволяет работать так с блоками, но реакт роутер почему то нарушает очерёдность, и блоки в DOM перепутаны, и получается что в доме последним лежит не нужный компонент.

**Вопрос:**  Подскажите как можно ругйлировать очередность отрисовки компонентов? В другом проекте я видел точно такую же архитектуру, и там очерёдность соблюдается.

```
"dependencies": {
    "react-router-config": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
  }
```

Comment: Проблема решена, извините за беспокойство

Comment: В таком случае стоит написать в ответе то, как именно она была решена.

Comment: Просто предыдущий программист зачем то написал  components.reverse();